# java web app jsp - active directory and tomcat SSO

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, tomcat, active-directory, single-sign-on

So I'm fairly new to Java EE and Tomcat so please keep things simple if possible. I am part of a Windows Active Directory. Until today, I had no idea such a thing like Active Directory existed just so you know where I am in knowledge of AD. From what I understand, I log into my windows desktop and my username and password would be passed to my outlook with the same username and password.

Now I would like to create a java web app that is on a tomcat 7.0 server that uses AD to login users to their specific page. This web app would exist on the intranet and would be accessible by everyone. But if they were to go to this page, the java app would use AD to recognize who that is and show a page that only that user is allowed to see.

For example, I go to a webpage and the java app would recognize me as AAA and show me page BBB. Now another user would go to the same webpage and the java app would recognize him as ZZZ and show him page YYY. I also need it so that there would be no windows prompt that asks for the username and password again.

Finally, what information would I need from AD (ie. connectionURL [thats the only one i know for sure]) and what kind of java lib would I need? I looked into WAFFLE, Kerberos and SPNEGO but not sure which was the easiest and quickest way of implementing this.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

I have a written a module for Apache Tomcat 6+ for exaclty that case: http://tomcatspnegoad.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

There is a detailed step-by-step guide for configuring this in the Tomcat documentation:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/windows-auth-howto.html

Given how new you are to AD, I suggest using Waffle as it is simpler to set up.